# Use Windows file explorer (file manager) of Win8 in Win7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, file-management

Is it possible in a Windows 7 OS to somehow install the official file explorer of Windows 8 OS?

Comment: mr./mrs. downvoter - suppose it is possible, wouldn't that be useful?

Comment: You can also try other file explorers. There are really other good ones in addition to Windows. +1 for the courage to ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't.

This part of the code is so deeply integrated into the OS (with countless hooks) that a) it is almost impossible to find out what to transfer and b) it will break things in your Windows 7 (at a minimum, your Explorer will no longer function).